# Why is properties in ItemAdding returning an ID of -1 for a User type SharePoint 2013?

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

I have created an event receiver for detecting duplicates on `ItemAdding`. It checks the username given (which is of type `Person or Group`) as well the value of another column, type `Lookup`. Here is my code for ItemAdding:

```
public override void ItemAdding(SPItemEventProperties properties)
    {
        base.ItemAdding(properties);
        if (properties.ListTitle.Equals("Runner"))
        {
            try
            {
                using (SPSite thisSite = new SPSite(properties.WebUrl))
                {
                    SPWeb thisWeb = thisSite.OpenWeb();
                    SPList list = thisWeb.Lists[properties.ListId];
                    var name = properties.AfterProperties["Name1"].ToString();
                    var nameFieldValue = new SPFieldLookupValue(name);
                    var nameId = nameFieldValue.LookupId;

                    var round = properties.AfterProperties["Round"].ToString();
                    var roundFieldValue = new SPFieldLookupValue(round);
                    var roundId = roundFieldValue.LookupId;

                    SPQuery query = new SPQuery();
                    query.Query = "<Where><And><Eq><FieldRef Name='Name1' LookupId='TRUE' /><Value Type='User'>" + Convert.ToString(nameId) + "</Value></Eq><Eq><FieldRef Name='Round' LookupId='TRUE' /><Value Type='Lookup'>" + Convert.ToString(roundId) + "</Value></Eq></And></Where>";
                    SPListItemCollection listItem = list.GetItems(query);
                    if (listItem.Count > 1)
                    {
                        properties.ErrorMessage = "Custom Error Message";
                        properties.Status = SPEventReceiverStatus.CancelWithError;
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new SPException(ex.Message.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
```

If I check the `nameId` it gives me a value of `-1`. When I check `name` I get something like `-1;#Robert`. I have written a separate console application to check the list once it has been added and the ID is added as `1`. Could someone please help?

Answer (score 1):

there is an issue.... Your using itemAdding, at this point in time the item still doesnt exist hence why it doesnt have an id but in itemAdded it does, you should compare on the text rather than id if you need to have it done within itemadding event,

so for you use itemAdded not adding!

```
public override void ItemAdding(SPItemEventProperties properties)
{
   string strName = string.Empty;

   foreach (DictionaryEntry entry in properties.AfterProperties)
   {
      if (entry.Key.Equals("Name1"))
      {
          strName = entry.Value.ToString();
      }
   }

   SPList list = properties.OpenWeb().Lists[properties.ListId];
   SPQuery query = new SPQuery();
   query.Query = "<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='" + list.Fields["Name1"].InternalName + "' /><Value Type='Text'>" + strName + "</Value></Eq></Where>";

   if (list.GetItems(query).Count > 0)
   {
      properties.Cancel = true;
      properties.ErrorMessage ="Sorry name already exists!";
   }
}
```

what is round and what value is it ment to return? i presume you want it to return unique values aswell?

as you can see in the code above you should return the internal name and check on that value! or you could try `list.Fields["Name1"].ID;` but as i noted the id doesnt exist yet at itemadding level but it does on item added as the item itself has not been added to the list so the id cannot exist.

**EDIT**

the returned value is correct, the reason your getting -1 is also correct! thats because in the event itemAdding when you run the code and the user is not part of UserInformatinList and so has no id so by default it returns -1 as the id value!

Round gives the correct value as its a lookup from within the list and not an spuser object your looking up against.

if the user is within the list of users for the web object UserInformatinList than it would have a corresponding id and return the users id correctly. So you need to use the code ensureuser to make sure that user is part of the web object list UserInformatinList or as i noted above have the code within the itemadded event.

so i presume its no good for itemadded, someone kindly has already worked out the ensure user for you!

```
    public static SPUser EnsureUserOnAddingOrUpdating(SPItemEventProperties properties, string newUserString)
    {
        SPUser user = null;
        if (properties.EventType != SPEventReceiverType.ItemAdding &&
            properties.EventType != SPEventReceiverType.ItemUpdating)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Method EnsureUserOnAddingOrUpdating must only be called on ItemAdding and ItemUpdating events.");
        }

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(newUserString))
        {
            SPFieldUserValue newUserValue = new SPFieldUserValue(properties.Web, newUserString);
            if (newUserValue.LookupId > 0)
                user = newUserValue.User;
            else if (newUserValue.LookupId < 0)
            {
                try
                {
                    user = properties.Web.EnsureUser(newUserValue.LookupValue);
                }
                catch (SPException ex)
                {
                      //catch exception here if not found in AD
                }
            }
        }

        return user;
    }
```

and your code to call above:

```
public override void ItemAdding(SPItemEventProperties properties)
{
    base.ItemAdding(properties);
    if (properties.ListTitle.Equals("Runner"))
    {
        try
        {
            using (SPSite thisSite = new SPSite(properties.WebUrl))
            {
                SPWeb thisWeb = thisSite.OpenWeb();
                SPList list = thisWeb.Lists[properties.ListId];


                var name = properties.AfterProperties["Name1"].ToString();
                var nameFieldValue = new SPFieldLookupValue(name);
                var nameId = nameFieldValue.LookupId;
                var nameString = nameFieldValue.LookupValue;

                //if id for user doesnt exist from lookup on web object then get it
                if (nameId == -1)
                {
                     //call the new method to get user id from web or AD
                     SPUser newUser = EnsureUserOnAddingOrUpdating(properties, nameString);
                     if (newUser != null)
                     {
                         nameId = newUser.Id;
                     }
                }


                var round = properties.AfterProperties["Round"].ToString();
                var roundFieldValue = new SPFieldLookupValue(round);
                var roundId = roundFieldValue.LookupId;

                SPQuery query = new SPQuery();
                query.Query = "<Where><And><Eq><FieldRef Name='Name1' LookupId='TRUE' /><Value Type='User'>" + Convert.ToString(nameId) + "</Value></Eq><Eq><FieldRef Name='Round' LookupId='TRUE' /><Value Type='Lookup'>" + Convert.ToString(roundId) + "</Value></Eq></And></Where>";
                SPListItemCollection listItem = list.GetItems(query);
                if (listItem.Count > 1)
                {
                    properties.ErrorMessage = "Custom Error Message";
                    properties.Status = SPEventReceiverStatus.CancelWithError;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new SPException(ex.Message.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

method above has been slightly re-coded to suit your needs but might need correcting slightly as i havent tested any changes!

http://dpruna.blogspot.co.uk/2011/09/using-spwebensureuser-in-itemadding-or.html#!/2011/09/using-spwebensureuser-in-itemadding-or.html

**EDIT** Updating issue:

as for updating that is not that simple to just use updating event as the before and after values are slightly different. you need to use AfterProperties for the new value the user wants to update with and properties.ListItem for the before value (origonal value)

http://www.synergyonline.com/Blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=122

Comment: Thank-you for your reply. I don't understand why the username is not valid as it is a user account in Windows. I am not creating a new Name, I am using an existing one.

And yes, Round is a Lookup list with values. This however seems to return the correct ID from the lookup?

Comment: im confused? i know your not creating a new account but the name your using properties.AfterProperties["Name1"].ToString(); , its that item id that doesnt exist, its created on item added not adding event.... the username itself is valid! so just to understand, you have two fields that your pulling values to check against. one is name and the other is round... round is correct but name is not (id value)?

Comment: Ahh... Right. Sorry, I am new to this. That is correct - round gives me an ID but the Name1 does not. Round is a lookup though so could it be pulling it from their? Also, when using ItemUpdating, how can I check that the item I am about to insert is not a duplicate without confusing it for one that may already be added?

Comment: just so i can give a correct solution, the lookup value from the list of names, is the value returned the first in the lookup list? seems like its returning the id from the current list and not from the actual lookup list itself if thats the case.

Comment: Thank-you for your reply. I have two lists, one is named Runners, the other is named Rounds. Inside Rounds, I have two columns -> One containing the round name (e.g. Round 1) and the other a Date. In Runners, I have a couple of columns but the ones I am interest in are Round and Name. Round is a lookup column for the Rounds list while Name is a Person or Group column where I insert a user account name in (Windows account so it must exist). I want to ensure that when I update or add a new item to the Runners list, no item in the list already will contain the same combination of Round and Name.

Comment: just updated my answer